# Git Show to different editor

Tags: git

I want the git show command to send the contents of the file to a different editor (e.g. Notepad++) instead of the default view.

I'm presuming this is possible by changing the git config but I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Git is not invoking an *editor* when you `git show` something, it is invoking your *pager*, and the two serve completely different purposes.

The setting you're after is `core.pager`, and you can configure it with `git config --global core.pager <your editor here>`, but it won't help if your editor can't be configured to read from stdin.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the next question is are there any text editors that can read from stdin? (I originally was thinking Notepad++)

Comment: Vim can, via `vim -`, but why would you want to do this? The output of a `diff` is fundamentally not editable. All you need to do is page through it. Are you sure you're not after a GUI-based pager? Because those do exist. There is really no reason to want to use an editor as a pager.

Comment: @meagar `git show VERSION:FILE` can be used to open a previous version of the given file, which, while not editable in the strict sense, is neither a diff.
Vim can be used to open the output with: `git show <smthg> | vim -` (along with a `:set filetype=<smthg>` to get the syntax coloring).