# save colored output from Git Show

Tags: git, git-show

Is there a way to save the colored output from a [git show](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show)?

I saw the post about using a [different editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359277/git-show-to-different-editor). But that is a lot more than what I'm trying to do. I just want to capture a report that is visually easy to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix your git command like so

```
 git -c color.status=always
```

And colour will always be produced

**Edit 2023:**

Above had not worked, but below had:

> if you want color codes in your redirected output, you can instead
> pass a
> --color flag to the Git command to force it to use color codes

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Answer (score 1):

You could use VIm with syntax highlight and the *TOhtml* command.

```
git show COMMIT:FILE.abc | vim -c "set filetype=abc" -c "TOhtml" -c "x git_show.html" -c "qa!" -
```

Where:

- FILE.abc is the file which will be shown in the past version defined by COMMIT hash code

**Note**:

1. The html result file will be named git_show.html and will be located in the current folder.
2. You must pass the 
   correct filetype replacing **abc** to another file extension, like
   *cpp*    or *java*.

Dissecting this long piped command:

*set filetype=**abc*** **:** activates the syntax highlight conforming to the **abc** type 
*TOhtml*               **:** makes VIm export the highlighted opened file to a HTML
*x git_show.html*  **:** **x** acts like wq, saving the file as git_show.html and then closing the current buffer. 
*qa!*                      **:** force VIm to exit without saving anything else
**-**  (trailing)           **:** makes VIm read from stdin