# Read from stdin into VS Code with specific file type

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, diff

I'd like to open a `git diff` output with VS Code. When I run `git diff | code -`, it opens in VS Code, but the file extension is set to *.txt*. I can manually "Change Language Mode" to Diff, but how can I do this automatically when viewing diffs in VS Code. I'd like to avoid always associating .txt with Diff if possible.

Comment: Looking for the same, seem to work in vim:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359277/git-show-to-different-editor#comment30235163_8360614

Comment: Looks like VS Code specifically rejected a command-line flag to specify language when reading from stdin:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/133811

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable to use a different command, I would use the `git difftool`. As written in the [documentation page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool)

> `git difftool` is a frontend to `git diff` and accepts the same options and arguments

I followed [this article](https://www.roboleary.net/vscode/2020/09/15/vscode-git.html) to configure VS Code as a difftool.

From a birds eye view:
Add VS Code to git config with these commands
`git config --global diff.tool vscode`
`git config --global difftool.vscode.cmd 'code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE'`

Then it is possible to call `git difftool ReadMe.md`. It brings up the VS Code with the diff window.